# Xcode 6, XCTest, "Expected expression"

Tags: xcode6, cocoapods, xctest

I'm no longer able to run my Test Bundle since switching to Xcode 6. We use Specta/Expecta/OCMock stack, but have older tests that use Vanilla XCTest. I'm on Cocoapods `0.34.0.rc2`, and `XCTest.h` seems to be importing just fine.

[image: Expected expression error]

[image: Expected expression error individual]

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue. It happened after upgrading to 0.34.0.rc2

Comment: Happening in 0.34.0.rc1 for what is worth...

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem. It might actually be unrelated with CocoaPods `0.34.0.rc2` as I too thought at the start, and being a Specta issue.

Commenting the code below, in `SpectaSupport.h`, fixes the build issue:

```
#undef _XCTRegisterFailure
#define _XCTRegisterFailure(condition, format...) \
({ \
_XCTFailureHandler((id)self, YES, __FILE__, __LINE__, condition, @"" format); \
})
```

More info [here](https://github.com/specta/specta/issues/85)